# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 when importing text file

Tags: java, android, text-files

```
String LoadCity (int ID) {
    //Here the magic starts: we import text file that we need
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + Integer.toString(ID), "raw", getPackageName());
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String line;
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line);
            content.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String toSplit = content.toString();
    return toSplit;
}
```

Error

> at com.superprower.aroundtheworld.gameactivity.LoadCity(gameactivity.java:88)

Points here:

> int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + Integer.toString(ID), "raw", getPackageName());
>           InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resId);

I want to import file cN, where N - is ID, conver it to string and return. File c1/c2/c3/c4 exists. Their are not TXT. It seems i getting resId somehow wrong. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
String uri = "raw/"+"c"+ID;
// int res = R.raw.c;
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
```

Comment: Can i convert it into something like 

String uri = "raw/c" + Integer.toString(ID);
?
Also, i need text file, not image. There is a text files contains some data, i want to import it to string and then split. I know i can use DB, but I am too lazy, and i can't remake half of my project.

Comment: Won't help. Still error on 
`InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resId);` , where resId is `int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());`

Comment: It's all in question. Problem is in `InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resId);`, it hasn't changed.

Comment: are you able to get resid by using this code int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

Comment: I able to get resID by both of ways - mine and yours. But still app is crashing because of Resource not Found error on line `InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resId);, `

Comment: Did you even readed question? File c1/c2/c3/c4 exists. Their inside the raw folder.

Comment: then check this resId is returning same resId you have in the raw folder or not : int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName())

Comment: Hm. Problem is much deeper then i expected. Weird, i send 1 to activity, but it's somehow turns to zero. TY anyway, i'll try to find other way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need some codes like these:

```
private final int getIdByNames(Context ctx, String resType, String fileName) {
    if (ctx == null || resType == null || fileName == null || "".equals(resType) || "".equals(fileName)) {
        return 0;
    }
    int id = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, resType, ctx.getPackageName());
    return id;
}
```

And these:

```
public final int getRawIdByName(Context ctx, String fileName) {
    return getIdByNames(ctx, "raw", fileName);
}
```

Then, maybe you need to call:

```
int resId = ResUtil.getRawIdByName(yourContext, "c1");
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
```